# Is it possible to pass variables to WordPress externally?

Tags: forms, variables, json

I would like to know if it is possible to pass json variables from a form which is located outside WordPress?
This is the situation: The user fills a form located on x server. Then his answers are sent to the WordPress site located in Y server in which depending upon his answer he will get an offer. I´ve been Googling to see if I can find an example but cant find none.

Could you please guide me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and there are a number of ways to go about doing this, all of them requiring that you can write code or find someone willing to write it for you.

One option would be to send your content via [ajax to admin-ajax.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) along with any wanted authentication tokens ... and then listen on admin-ajax.php and process accordingly.

Another would be to create your own endpoint that checks for particular post data and then, if it looks correct, loads wordpress and adds what you need. For this you might search for bootstrapping wordpress or look at index.php in the wordpress root directory and see how it loads wordpress ... then do the same when needed.

There are probably a lot of other methods as well, but those two are relatively simple to implement and would do what you want to do.

Also, you might check out [wp-api.org](http://wp-api.org/), which I just stumbled on via a post from kaiser on a different thread here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to apply and see how it goes. But thank you very much for giving me an insight of what I could do

Comment: Very welcome. Also, you might check out wp-api.org.